# How to put H264 encoded data, inside a container like .mp4 using libAV libraries (ffmpeg)?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, codec, libavcodec, libavformat

I have been playing around with the libAV* family of libraries, that comes along with FFMPEG and I am learning how to implement things like encoding, decoding, muxing etc.

I came across this code : https://libav.org/documentation/doxygen/master/encode_video_8c-example.html  , that encodes, YUV frames, to a file, using an encoder. In my implementation, I will change the encoder to H264 using `avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264)`  But I do not know, how to put this encoded data, into a proper container (.mp4) using libav libraries, so that the output file, can be played by any media player like VLC, QuickTime, etc...

Can anyone please help me on that? Every help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The example only writes raw encoded data into an arbitrary file. What you want to do is to write encoded data into a (media) container file, like mp4. Have a look at this example: [ffmpeg - muxing](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-example.html)

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Thankyou very much! I've already read muxing.c, but I have a doubt, why isn't c->framerate not explicitly set by the function ```add_stream```, when the case is  AVMEDIA_VIDEO_TYPE?

Comment: The framerate is set in the file muxing.c, in function [add_stream](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c_source.html#l00124), at line 189. The field `framerate` is not what you think it is, see [here](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html#a4d08b297e97eefd66c714df4fff493c8).

Comment: @ErdalKüçük So, it's framerate for CRF, and not the actual video? So, If I explicitly set it to say (AVRational){25, 1};  then is it mandatory to call av_set_opt to set "CRF" to some value?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Please, read my previous message

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Since, I want to encode to H264 are there any special values, that need to be set for ```max_b_frames``` or ```gop_size``` that need to be set, for H264? Likewise, should any additional options be set using ```AVDictionary```, for ```avformat_write_header()``` ?

Comment: So many questions. When you set the field framerate and open the codec, the field will be recognized, no need for the call to av_opt_set. Every codec share common parameters with other codecs (e.g. gop_size, aka keyframes) but there are also codec specific parameters. ffmpeg will set the fields to default values (so it is not necessary to set them) but for fine tuning, have a look at the codec documentation and figure out how to set them in ffmpeg. Note: some parameters are mandatory, like size, pixelformat, timebase, etc. Either you set the fields for each class directly or via AVDictionary.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Sorry, for too many questions! Thankyou very much! :)

Comment: It' a long time since i've used ffmpeg. I had to dig some things up. But have a look at [av_codec_open2()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavc__core.html#ga11f785a188d7d9df71621001465b0f1d) param **options:** _A dictionary filled with AVCodecContext and codec-private options. On return this object will be filled with options that were not found._. So, instead of setting the fields directly, you specify them by a `AVDictionary`, as a result, you get the unrecognized options.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük So, can I pass that dictionary as an argument to ```avformat_write_header()``` ?

Comment: Don't forget to read the docs. Codec options into `avcodec_open2()` and format options into [avformat_write_header()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga18b7b10bb5b94c4842de18166bc677cb) param **options:** _An AVDictionary filled with AVFormatContext and muxer-private options_.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Okay:)

Comment: If you have only one single dict, unrecognized parameters are returned as a result, in both cases.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Why "muxing.c" does not use: ```avcodec_parameters_from_context``` to set ```AVStream::codecpar``` ???

Comment: What's the thing in line 447?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Okay! I see, my bad. Is it okay to call ```avcodec_parameters_from_context``` BEFORE ```avcodec_open2``` ??? The documentation is silent about ordering it?

Comment: Look what [avcodec_parameters_from_context()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/codec__par_8c_source.html#l00090) does and then look what [avcodec_open2()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avcodec_8c_source.html#l00137) does and then think again about your question. This has to be your further approach!

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Okay! Wow, this is so fragile, like the wings of a Dragonfly! :)

Comment: Welcome to the world of programming / open source! And of course it's ffmpeg, no more to say.

Comment: Don't use the documentation for Libav (the dead fork of FFmpeg that they annoyingly named after the FFmpeg libav libraries) if you are using FFmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write the frames to a file you initialize something like this:

```
// Have the library guess the format
AVOutputFormat *fmt = av_guess_format(NULL, "my_video.mp4", NULL);

// Set the AVOutputFormat in your output context (init not shown)
pOutFormatContext->oformat = fmt;

// Open the output, error handling not shown
avio_open2(&pOutFormatContext->pb, "my_video.mp4", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, NULL, NULL);

// Create output stream
AVStream * outStream;
outStream = avformat_new_stream(pOutFormatContext, NULL);

// Set any output stream options you would want, example of setting the aspect ratio from the input coded 'inCodecContext' (init not shown for this)
outStream->sample_aspect_ratio.num = inCodecContext->sample_aspect_ratio.num;
outStream->sample_aspect_ratio.den = inCodecContext->sample_aspect_ratio.den;

// There may be other things you want to set like the time base, but will depend on what you're doing

// Write the header to the context, error handling not shown
avformat_write_header(pOutFormatContext, NULL);

// Dump out the format and check
av_dump_format(pOutFormatContext, 0, pOutFormatContext->filename, 1);
```

You then have to read the packets and encode them which it sounds like you're already doing, and then when you write to the output context it should be writing to the file in the container you specified.